# joining two tables with multiple conditions in rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two tables named `lines`  and `attribute_values`. From that I want to select the fields `name` from the `lines` tables with conditions given in the MySQL query below:

```
select distinct a.name 
from lines a join attribute_values b 
where a.advertiser_id = 280 
  and a.id = b.line_id 
  and b.name in (11, 18) 
  and b.value != 0;
```

How do I write this query using Ruby code?

Comment: do u have any associations between your models ? if yes then please show them.

Comment: yes, having has_many relationship

Comment: What code have you written as an attempted solution?

Answer (score 0):

Assume 
Line has_many attribute_values

Try this

```
Line.joins(:attribute_values).select("DISTINCT(lines.name)").where("lines.advertiser_id = ? AND attribute_values.name IN (?) AND attribute_values.value != ?", 280, [11,18], 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

To get distinct value you have to apply `uniq`.

```
Lines.joins(:attribute_values).where('lines.advertiser_id = ? AND attribute_values.name in ? AND attribute_values.value <> ?', 280, [11, 18], 0).uniq
```

Comment: seems like a typo here
`lines.advertiser_id ? ` should be `lines.advertiser_id = ? `
isnt it ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Line.joins("a LEFT JOIN attribute_values b ON a.id = b.line_id").select("DISTINCT(a.name)").where("b.value != ? AND b.name in (?) AND a.advertiser_id = ?", 0, [11, 18], 280)
```