# Active Record query to find records that match all conditions in Rails has_many through relationship

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have two models, Apartments and Amenities, which are associated through ApartmentAmenities. I am trying to implement a filter where I only show apartments that have *all* of the amenities specified.

```
class Amenity < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_many :apartment_amenities
  has_many :apartments, through: :apartment_amenities
end

class ApartmentAmenity < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :apartment
  belongs_to :amenity
end

class Apartment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :apartment_amenities
  has_many :amenities, through: :apartment_amenities
end
```

I've got a query working that will return all apartments that match at least one of the amenities of given set like so:

```
Apartment.joins(:apartment_amenities).where('apartment_amenities.amenity_id IN (?)', [1,2,3])
```

but this isn't quite what I'm going for.

Comment: To get distinct value you have to apply uniq. maybe try this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18015859/joining-two-tables-with-multiple-conditions-in-rails

Comment: @NinjaBoy I tried that. It's not quite what I'm going for since it still gives me apartments that have one amenity but not the other. I need only apartments that have all of the amenity ids given

Comment: try adding `.having('COUNT(*) >= ?', amenity_ids_array.length)` at the end of your line. You will need to set `amenity_ids_array = [1,2,3]`. And if for some reason you can find duplicates in the `ApartmentAmenty` model, then you need to add a `distinct` clause to avoid counting the same Apartment-Amenity relation twice. EDIT: you will need to group your results before using `having`.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but how do I group the results?

Comment: Give `Apartment.joins(:apartment_amenities).group('apartments.id').where('apartment_amenities.amenity_id IN (?)', [1,2,3]).having("COUNT(*) >= ?", [1,2,3].length)` a try.

Comment: But how this works? let say, an apartment'samenities are [1,2,4,5], then also I think, it will show in result but it should not.

Comment: @Nikhil Good point. I just checked and you're right, it is flawed. Back to square 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, after giving up for a few days then getting back to it, I finally found this question: [How to find records, whose has_many through objects include all objects of some list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18955190/how-to-find-records-whose-has-many-through-objects-include-all-objects-of-some)

Which led me to the answer that works properly:

```
  def self.with_amenities(amenity_ids)
    where("NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM amenities
      WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM apartment_amenities
        WHERE apartment_amenities.amenity_id = amenities.id
        AND apartment_amenities.apartment_id = apartments.id)
      AND amenities.id IN (?))", amenity_ids)
  end
```